# Простой вопрос по игре

Tags: python, python-3.x

Пишу простейшую игру на python. Игра угадай число

Компьютер загадывает число от 1 до 50 и даёт 6 попыток пользователю, 
чтобы тот смог угадать загаданное число. Когда пользователь вводит число, 
компьютер проверяет угадано ли число и если не угадано, то сообщает пользователю меньше ли или больше загаданное число. 
Если пользователь угадал - то сообщает о том, что число отгадано.

```py
import random

print('Привет! Добро пожаловать в игру "Угадай число".')

s = 1
while s < 7:
    n = int(input('Введи число от 1 до 10 и нажми Enter: ')) # число пользователя
    pc = random.randint(1, 10)
    if 1 <= n <= 10:
        if n == pc:
            print('Уррраа Ты угадал!!!')
            print(f'Ты загадал число {n}, а компьютер загадал {pc}. \nЭто потрясающе!!!')
            break
        else:
            print(f'Ну вот, не угадал. Оказывается, компьютер загадал число {pc}')
            print(f'У тебя осталось {6 - s} попыток' )
    else:
        print("Ошибка !!! Введи число из диапазона от 0 до 10")
        #print(f'У тебя осталось {6 - s} попыток' )
    s = s + 1
```

Вопрос такой: почему когда все попытки заканчиваются, выводится сообщение, "У тебя осталось 0 попыток". Как изменить код, чтобы это сообщение не выводилось на последнем шаге.

Comment: Я бы на вашем месте воспользовался конструкцией `for i in range(6): ... else: ...`. Внутри `for` вызвать `break`, если пользователь угадал, а внутри `else` будет код, отвечающий за ситуацию, когда не угадал за 6 попыток.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам надо добавить проверку `if s != 6:`

```
import random

print('Привет! Добро пожаловать в игру "Угадай число".')

s = 1
while s < 7:
    n = int(input('Введи число от 1 до 10 и нажми Enter: ')) # число пользователя
    pc = random.randint(1, 10)
    if 1 <= n <= 10:
        if n == pc:
            print('Уррраа Ты угадал!!!')
            print(f'Ты загадал число {n}, а компьютер загадал {pc}. \nЭто потрясающе!!!')
            break
        else:
            print(f'Ну вот, не угадал. Оказывается, компьютер загадал число {pc}')
            if s != 6:
                print(f'У тебя осталось {6 - s} попыток' )
    else:
        print("Ошибка !!! Введи число из диапазона от 0 до 10")
        #print(f'У тебя осталось {6 - s} попыток' )
    s = s + 1
```